# Menu item text being clipped in unmodified basic activity

Tags: android

Note: I've not added any code or modifications to this.

For some unknown reason, the stock AndroidStudio - basic activity - menu item's text is being clipped. I've tried recreating this in blank activity and had the exact same issue.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.gmail.islarf.derekbanas_learningandroid.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

[image: androidstudio_designview_clippedmenuitem]

Comment: have you tried app:showAsAction="always" !, if didn't work just remove the whole line

Comment: I don't want it on the actionbar, i still want the text as a menu item.

Answer (score 0):

change `app:showAsAction="never"` to `app:showAsAction="always|withText"` and `android:showAsAction="always|withText"` set order to 1

Comment: unable to use 'android:showAsAction="always|withText" ' alerts with 

'Should use app:showAsAction with the appcompat library with xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" '.